# Questions about increment operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, identity-column

I have a table with a field that increments. The values for that field are `1, 2, 3...60` and then the field is `1060`.

I don't know why?

The next value for id must be `61`.

Comment: Did you delete any data from the table?  If you did then you might need to reseed the identity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset AutoIncrement in SqlServer after Delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510121/reset-autoincrement-in-sqlserver-after-delete)

Comment: If you're relying on your `IDENTITY` field always having an unbroken "chain" of integer values then I'm afraid you're using it for the wrong purpose. `IDENTITY` fields are **surrogate keys** and therefore have no real-world meaning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2012 column identity increment jumping from 6 to 1000+ on 7th entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162648/sql-server-2012-column-identity-increment-jumping-from-6-to-1000-on-7th-entry)

Answer (score 3):

This is a new feature of SQL Server 2012. Identity columns use [`Sequences`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) and values are cashed by default to speed up when inserting new rows. When **unplanned shutdown** of SQL Server occurs, cache is lost and Identity values continue with gap (of usually 1000 or 10000) created.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons - some of the most likely:

- 999 records were deleted
- 999 inserts were attempted and failed
- Something reset the identity value using `DBCC CHECKIDENT ({table}, RESEED, {value});`
- Something inserted a record with a specific ID using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`

Autoincrement fields are ***not*** guaranteed to be *consecutive*.  Thy are guaranteed to be *unique*.  If you need them to be consecutive, then I would recommend keeping track of the next ID yourself, which will require you to think about concurrency, foreign key references, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming you mean an [IDENTITY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) field with an increment of 1.
This increases the value by 1 each time a new record is inserted.

To quote:

> If an identity column exists for a table with frequent deletions, gaps
>   can occur between identity values. If this is a concern, do not use
>   the IDENTITY property. However, to ensure that no gaps have been
>   created or to fill an existing gap, evaluate the existing identity
>   values before explicitly entering one with SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON.

As alluded to in the comments it's likely this table once had data populated with all the missing values but these were deleted. (As this is quite a big chunk maybe this was done in bulk?)