# Sql server strange Identity increment

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have this table setup at SQL Azure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sl](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PublicId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey_ba033f1f-ac1b-4616-8591-fcd47fe0f63d] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON),
 CONSTRAINT [PublicId_UNIQUE] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [PublicId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

The very strange thing is that the ID gets incremented in a unexpected way.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
1011
1012
1013
1014
1015
1019
1020
1021
1022
1023
1024
1025
1026
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024
2025
2026
2027
2028
2029
2030
2031
2032
2033
2034
2035
2036
2037
2038
2039
2040
2041
2042
2043
2044
2045
2046
2047
2048
2049
2050
2051
2052
2053
2054
2055
2056
2057
2058
2059
2060
2061
2062
2063
2064
2065
2066
2067
2068
2069
2070
2071
2072
2073
3073
3074
3075
3076
3077
3078
3079
3080
3081
3082
3083
3084
3085
3086
3087
3088
3089
3090
3091
3092
4091
4092
4093
5091
5092
5093
5094
5095
5096
5097
5098
5099
5100
5101
5102
5103
5104
5105
6091
6092
7091
7092
7093
7094
7095
7096
7097
7098
7099
7100
7101
7102
7103
7104
7105
7106
7107
8091
8092
8093
8094
8095
8096
8097
9091
9097
9098
9099
9100
9101
9102
9103
9104
9105
9106
9107
9108
9109
9110
9111
9112
9113
9114
9115
9116
9117
10100
10117
10118
10119
10120
10121
10122
10123
10124
10125
10126
11126
11127
11128
11129
11130
11131
11132
11133
11134
11135
11136
11137
11138
11139
11140
11141
11142
11143
11144
11145
11146
12144
12145
12146
12147
12148
12149
12150
12151
12152
12153
12154
12155
12156
12157
12158
12159
12160
12161
12162
12163
12164
12165
12166
12167
12168
12169
12170
12171
12172
12173
12174
12175
12176
12177
12178
12179
12180
12181
12182
12183
13183
13184
13185
13186
13187
13188
13189
13190
13191
13192
13193
13194
13195
13196
13197
13198
13199
13200
13201
13202
13203
14202
14203
14204
14205
14206
14207
14208
14209
14210
14211
14212
14213
14214
15214
15215
15216
15217
15218
15219
15220
15221
15222
15223
15224
15225
15226
15227
15228
15229
15230
15231
15232
15233
16233
16234
16235
16236
16237
16238
16239
16240
16241
16242
16243
16244
16245
16246
16247
16248
16249
```

Any idea how to make this increment normally?
So that the numbers don't jump like that?
Any idea how to make this increment normally?
So that the numbers don't jump like that?

Comment: similar on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162648/sql-server-2012-column-identity-increment-jumping-from-6-to-1000-on-7th-entry

Comment: Kind of similar, except your options in the cloud are extremely limited.

Comment: If you're relying on the numeric values of `IDENTITY` columns in any way, you're doing things wrong. They should be treated as opaque blobs - that only server to identify the row - and that conveniently can be *stored* in numeric columns. If you're relying on the "values", you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identity increment is jumping in SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue. There are two related items reported on Connect. This one is actually closed as by design, but I don't think the engineer who left the comment really understood the issue:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/743300/identity-column-jumps-by-seed-value

This (earlier!) bug is active:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity

The latter has one interesting workaround, and others that raise my eyebrows. The primary workaround on [the suggested dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162648/sql-server-2012-column-identity-increment-jumping-from-6-to-1000-on-7th-entry) would be fine for your own box, but good luck running a trace flag in Azure (or creating a startup proc as one of the connect items suggested). Using a SEQUENCE with no cache may be a viable option, but you should validate that the trade-offs are worth avoiding gaps in a meaningless, surrogate number. The other answer there suggests issuing a CHECKPOINT after every insert. Ouch.

In the end, if you want a sequence without gaps, stop using `IDENTITY` - that's not what it was designed to do.

Comment: This is very upsetting

Comment: @user3077725 Upsetting, why? You have gaps. Big deal. The values shouldn't have any meaning, and gaps can't really be avoided with IDENTITY anyway, even if this bug didn't exist. Just make it a BIGINT and forget about it. It won't be fixed any time soon.

Comment: Why wont it be fixed anytime soon? Is this not really a flaw? I have never dealt with this until I started using azure

Comment: @masteroleary the change was by design for performance reasons. I don't think they quite anticipated how many people would be affected by this, because (a) how many people are depending on identity to be gapless (something neither explicitly documented nor implicitly promised) and (b) how many people are restarting their servers frequently enough for this to be a problem. If you want to wait for a fix, by all means, go ahead. In the meantime you either need to stop caring about gaps of any size, or implement a workaround.

Comment: As to why someone might care about the gaps. I wanted to use a base-36 value based off of the identity. With gaps, the base-36 code the user enters is going to grow in length more quickly. I've seen a couple projects storing their own identity / ticket to hand out (incrementing a value in blob storage, I think) but locking / performance?  Since Sql Azure can hand out an identity, I though I'd use that but if gaps are large and/or frequent...? Is there a better architecture for handing out unique +1 sequential tickets?

Comment: Have not tried it yet but here is the link to one of the sequence id projects I was referencing: http://candordeveloper.com/2013/10/22/sequenceid-generator-for-azure-or-any-big-table-storage/

Comment: @Timothy if unique / gapless trumps performance, stop thinking about shortcuts like identity and sequence. Use a serializable max+1 technique or your own centralized, serializable sequence.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks, I have forked SnowMaker and am working on making it compatible with Azure Mobile Services.