# SQL Auto increment random behaviour

Tags: sql-server, database

In the SQL Server database(2012), I have a product table. ProductID which is the primary key has auto increment by 1. 
This database is being accessed by several users and add new content. (this is a development server)
Suddenly the primary key went up to 1000's from 60's.
How can this happen? 
I am using Entity Framework to update/add data. We have not deleted anything yet.
Here is how ID's being generated,

1..66 was fine.
66
67
68
69
70
71
1012
2012
3012
3013
3014
3015....3019 is fine

Comment: [Did you search first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442543/sql-server-strange-identity-increment/)? And why do you care about gaps? IDENTITY doesn't guarantee "no gaps" anyway...

Comment: Identity should be just about uniqueness anyway, if you need to have gapless numbering for lets say bookkeeping then you need to work different logic.

Comment: I also encountered that using Entity Framework even in SQL AZURE.  It is a bug in the Entity Framework.

Answer (score -1):

Try to order it by your Id and see what happens