# inserting 1 million records with sequence and select max

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i tried to insert 1 million rows in a test table using sequence and using the query (using select max) which i posted below. Surprisingly, the query with with select max created 1 million rows in 11:11 (11 mins 11 secs)

And the query with sequence create 1 million rows in 19:34 (19 mins 11 secs). now i am not sure which is good

Table : SitePage

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SitePage](
    [PageID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PageName] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SitePage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PageID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

here are the queries

1. Query to create Sequence

   ```
   create Sequence PageTableSequence
   START WITH 1
   INCREMENT BY 1
   NO CYCLE
   NO CACHE
   ;
   ```
2. Query to create 1 million records using Select max(id)

   ```
   DECLARE @intFlag INT
   SET @intFlag = 0
   Declare @maxrecords bigint
   set @maxrecords = 0
   while(@maxrecords<1000000)

   BEGIN
   WHILE (@intFlag =0)
   BEGIN
     BEGIN TRY
     Insert into SitePage (PageID, PageName) values ((Select max(PageID)+1  from SitePage),'Some Page Name');
     set @intFlag = @@rowcount

     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
     SET @intFlag=0
     END CATCH

   END
   set @maxrecords = @maxrecords+1
   set @intFlag=0
   END

   GO
   ```
3. Query using Sequence to insert 1 million records

   ```
   Declare @maxrecords bigint
   set @maxrecords = 0    

   while(@maxrecords<1000000)    

   BEGIN      

     Insert into SitePage (PageID, PageName) values (next value for PageTableSequence, 'some page name');

     set @maxrecords = @maxrecords+1

   END

   GO
   ```

why there is such a difference in sequence and select max

Comment: And... what's the problem?

Comment: That is strange, I would expect the sequence to be alot faster than using max(PageId).

Comment: Hi.  It looks like you are stuck because you are afraid of an overhead issue.  Is there a way you can duplicate your table so you have a test table to work with? that way you can see for yourself.  Next...are you familiar with the stack exchange code review site?  That would be an excellent question for that site.  Consider your question, (which is better?) We can't function well with those type of open ended questions here.  Stack Overflow is for break fix question primary and discover questions secondary.

Comment: @FrankTudor I don't think this is a "which is better" question.  It's a "why do sequences perform so badly".  I guess it could have been worded better.

Comment: So you had a difference in one test.  Lots of stuff goes on in a server.  Run it 1000 times.   You have created your test table.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try not using "NO CACHE", but use "CACHE 100", or even 1000 instead.  This should give reduce IO and improve performance.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: +1 to you sir for answering his question...I moved along like everyone else because I felt it more of an opinion question.

Comment: The test was to generate continuous primary key values wihtout break, even after server restart. Currently, sql server 2012 will create gaps of 10000 for bigint datatype when there is a server restart. Even with cache. the objective is to test against no cache

Comment: If it helps, there are some tips for dealing with the [identity gaps in Sql Server 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14162648/458354)