# Should I use an int or a long for the primary key in an entity framework model

Tags: c#, model, int, primary-key, entity-framework-6

I am writing an MVC5 Internet application and I have a question about the id field for a model.

Should I use an int or a long for the id in a model? I am talking about the field that is used for the primary key? Is an int enough if the database has 100,000s of records? Is an int in c# different than an int in a SQL database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please note that if the primary key property of your Code First class is a `long` type, you may need to add the `[Key]` DataAnnotation to the property

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are OK. It depends on how many records will be in a table. Int allows only 2*10^9 records per table.

If you are sure, that 2*10^9 is enough, use int as a key.

But:
If there is a tiny chance that count of records will be more than 2*10^9, use the long. 
If you don't have any idea how many records you'll have, use long.

Comment: The size is not 2*10^9, it's 2^31

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch: 2^10 = 1024 It is about 10^3. 2^31 = 2*2^9. Therefore it is about 2*(10^3)^3 = 2*10^9

Answer (score 70):

With a type `INT`, starting at 1, you get **over 2 billion** possible rows - that should be more than sufficient for the vast majority of cases. With `BIGINT`, you get roughly **922 quadrillion** (922 with 15 zeros - 922'000 billions) - enough for you??

If you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert **one row every second**, around the clock, you need 66.5 **years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ....

If you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` (`BIGINT` in T-SQL is defined as `long` or `Int64` in .NET languages) starting at 1, and you insert **one thousand rows every second**, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....

Read more about it (with all the options there are) in the [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

Comment: Add 1000 to the counter for every SQL service shut down unexpectedly / failure because the server saves 1000 numbers ahead in the cache and doesn't place them back on failure so you can easily see jumps of 1000's in your identity columns. I would easily go for the 'long' (Int64) version in every identity column I define. In case you are not aware of this behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14162761/665783

Answer (score 6):

Both C# and SQL have the same definition for an `int`, which is an integral data type that goes from `-2^31` to `2^31 - 1` (2,147,483,647 if you prefer).

As you can see, your 100,000s of records could fit more than 20,000 times in an `int`, so **yes**, you will be alright in your current scenario.

A `long` however would translate into a `bigint` in sql (there's no "long" per se), and the value caps at `2^63 - 1`.