# Identity increment jumping in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the exact reason for identity increment jumping after restarting SQL Server?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162648/sql-server-2012-column-identity-increment-jumping-from-6-to-1000-on-7th-entry?rq=1) and many more like it. If you want sequential numbers without gaps, `IDENTITY` is the wrong tool. But more likely, the desire for sequential numbers without gaps is the wrong demand and identity is a fine tool.

Comment: There are things that use Identity values and they're not put back in case of rollbacks/non-commits etc because identity isn't a guaranteed unbroken sequence - and shouldn't be used as such.

Comment: not desiring or demanding sequential numbers ..just wanted to know the reason why does it happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly then you are probably facing this issue [Failover or Restart Results in Reseed of Identity](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity). The reason is, when you allocate the IDENTITY values then a cache size of 1000 is allocated, so when you are restart the unused values are lost.