# SQL Server 2012 huge jump on identity seed 1,000,000,000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012 database with a table that has an identity column that has jumped by several hundred million:

- Identity seed: 10
- Identity increment: 1
- Data Type: bigint

  4000012345 to 5000000001

There was potentially a record inserted around the time of the issue with:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT orders ON
SET IDENTITY_INSERT orders OFF
```

I’m currently trying to find the TSQL of the record in the transaction log and will update accordingly.

After a restart of the server yesterday this issue was also apparent:
[SQL Server 2012 column identity increment jumping from 6 to 1000+ on 7th entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162648/sql-server-2012-column-identity-increment-jumping-from-6-to-1000-on-7th-entry)

However, I don’t think this issue would explain such a large jump but may be related.

Please can anyone offer any advice on alternative places to look or provide a potential explanation?

---

The jump of 10,000 I can understand and have observed after restart of server.

I can find very little online of references to such a large jump. I have concerns if this happens multiple times there is the potential for no IDs to be available.

Comment: It looks like a reseed. However, you cannot rely on consecutive numbers anyways, so this "jump" should not be an issue since there's plenty of room in the `bigint`.

Comment: SQL Server does *not* guarantee that `identity` columns are gapless.  In fact, there are many cases where gaps appear (notable only failed inserts and when numbers are "pre-allocated" for bulk inserts).  I will admit that your gap does seem rather large.

Comment: I think what you encountered is a reseed based on a new sequence, which would be a duplicate of the Q you referenced. I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate; and because this one is using `bigint` the sequence chunk is just bigger than with a normal int. I'm therefore voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2012 column identity increment jumping from 6 to 1000+ on 7th entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162648/sql-server-2012-column-identity-increment-jumping-from-6-to-1000-on-7th-entry)

Comment: @Lucero, with `bigint` type the cache size of `IDENTITY` is 10,000, not 1,000,000. So, this jump should be caused by something different.

Comment: The cache size may not be at the default - maybe a `SELECT * FROM sys.sequences` could shed some light into whether this was the issue or not.

Comment: As for running out of IDs... you can do this 9'223'372'036 times until you run out of IDs (`bigint` range is 2^63 = 9'223'372'036'854'775'808). Not an issue I think.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. @Lucero I've tried running this and no results come back.

Comment: It's the large jump that concerns me.