# EntityFramework Code First - Sql Server Database Id Error

Tags: entity-framework, unit-of-work

When i insert a new record,Sql server database table is not save well-order auto increment.How can i solve it?
[image: database table id increment of 1000]

[image]

w

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent collisions in rapid insertions, Sql Server provides a default CACHE value for the auto incremented column. You should not rely on the order of this column for the insert sequence of the records.
You can use a sequence generator with the NO CACHE setting as explained
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14162761/4014106)