# DatabaseGenerated DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity does not generate sequential numbers

Tags: c#, mysql, database-design

I have the following model:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key]
public string Id { get; set; }

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
```

I would like `OrderNumber` to increment by 1 every time. However for some strange reason I get the following sequences:
`1,2,3,4,..., 75, 1075, 1076, 1077, 1078,..., 1086, 2086, 2087, 2088,...`

For some strange reason they go in a sequence incrementing by one but every now and then it jumps with 1000.

I would appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction for debugging.

Comment: That is unrelated to C#/Entity Framework. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162648/sql-server-2012-column-identity-increment-jumping-from-6-to-1000-on-7th-entry

Comment: Note that even without this weird behaviour identity is not guaranteed to not have gaps (say if transaction fails for whatever reason - id will not be reused later).

Comment: which is the primary key? Id or OrderNumber?

Comment: @Ramakrishnan the primary is the `Id`, which is not the issue I am having trouble.

Comment: thanks @CamiloTerevinto, I ended up removing that logic and simply implementing my own numbering

Comment: @mgPePe As long as you ensure it's done in a database transaction atomically, it should all be good :)

Comment: MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT` does not have jumps _like that_.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I suspect you are looking the wrong place.